# How to implement box2d light when using scene2d in libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, scene2d

We are making a game using libgdx and we want to know the way to use the light and physics from box2D with the scene2d, It seems that to get light you need be into a World class which contains the required stuff, but I don't know how to get both together.

Answer (score 1):

I am dealing with similar issues. This blogpost seems to hold some answers:

http://pimentoso.blogspot.com/2013/01/meter-and-pixel-units-in-box2d-game.html